# Issue with link_to method in rails 3.2

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

We are upgrading rails from 2.3.5 to 3.2.1. While upgrading we are getting issue with link_to method.We have the following code snippet.

link_to( name, path_options, html_options, *params )

Here name is: 
    `<span class='bmark_link_tag'><img alt="Post this blog to Stumbleupon"     src="/images/png/stumble.png" />&nbsp;Stumbleupon</span>`

But while rendering it is directly displaying the above name value instead of displaying image in UI.

Could you please help us on this ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use image_tag in link_to as,

```
<%= link_to image_tag("images/png/stumble.png", :alt=>"Post this blog to Stumbleupon", :class=>"bmark_link_tag")+"Stumbleupon", your_path %>
```